# When designing a programming language, do designers fully specify its operational/denotational semantics?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, formal-languages

For languages that appear in academic conferences like [POPL](https://popl19.sigplan.org) or [ICFP](https://www.icfpconference.org/), often the language's semantics (in the form of [operational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) or [denotational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) semantics) are well specified. I was trying to find documented semantics for popular languages (e.g., C, Python, JavaScript) but couldn't find any.

When such languages with "heavy" (relatively heavy to languages designed as proofs of concept) features are being developed, do designers (or committee members) of those languages add features without specifying their semantics? And is that the case for most popular programming languages?

If so, I think it makes sense practically because not every person who wants to contribute to developing a language needs to be a PL researcher. But I was wondering about what kind of real-world trade-offs exist.

Comment: ecmascript (javascript) semantics are exhaustively specified time in [ECMA standard 262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of some dynamic programming languages are emerging, because they are minimal in their syntactical core, and are mostly defined by their libraries (the language that is actually used for programming is much lager than what is defined by the syntax). Examples are:

- LISP
- PERL
- TCL

Some languages are defined with so much syntactic ambiguity that the semantics end up being defined by the particular implementation. Examples:

- Early C++
- C++ with STL
- AG Natural

Any programming language with macro capabilities, or that is normally used with a macro preprocessor ends up with semantics being redefined by the macros used (like in *Domain Specific Languages*). Dynamic languages that allow changes to the parsing behavior at runtime are also defined at runtime.

In object-oriented languages (and other languages that dispatch depending on the type of the objects) the semantics of an expression depend on the types of the objects involved, and those may depart largely from the semantics of equivalent expressions for built-in and standard types.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all languages are defined usually with a normative notation such as BNF. [This site has references to many](http://slebok.github.io/zoo/index.html).

Part of this is to remove ambiguities and ensure syntactic consistency. It would be difficult to build compilers or renderers without them.

Parts of this go into the [design of HTML5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/introduction.html) which explains some of the reasoning.

Comment: You seem to be talking about syntax here, but the question is about semantics.